# How can I apply a script component to every subelement in hierarchy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written a script called `door.cs`. Now I would like to apply this script to every game object that is a child object of `doors` (hierarchy window left side) without doing so manually.

I am looking for a way to apply `door.cs` to all child objects of `doors`.

Comment: You can multi-select and add the component to all selected.  Otherwise look into editor scripts.

Comment: There is an attribute called [Contextmenu](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html)

Comment: I think multi-select is a solution. Can you elaborate on Contextmenu @GhostThePunisher

Comment: Let's clarify please. By category do you mean `Tag`? Or do you mean `Object Type`? You want to do this during Edit Mode only and only in the Editor? (not Runtime, not Editor Play Time). When you say you want to drag the "gamecomponents", do you mean components as in "behaviours" or "game objects"? What are "sub-elements"? You started talking about "game objects", then you asked about "gamecomponents" and now you talk about "sub-elements" but it sounds like you're referring to the same thing. Also note there is a concept known as "child object" (which you *might* mean as a "sub-element"?).

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right and `child object` is the correct vocabulary. I simplified the question by leaving out irrelevant information.

Comment: ```[ContextMenu]``` is a tag, which makes your functions in your common scripts available in a context menu of that component(where you reset, copy component, etc...). So if there is something you can do at runtime using the ```[ContextMenu]``` tag you can do it in editor mode as well.